# Disable SSID broadcast

Tags: wireless-networking

I set up temporary private wireless networks at large public gatherings for the purpose of machine control in my audio system. I am the only user. I notice that my network performance degrades noticably as soon as 4000 people walk in to the room with their cell phones. I assume that some percentage of the devices in the room are discovering my network and attempting to connect. I further assume that if the network were 'invisable', many less devices would try to log on, thus improving overall throughput for me...? Does this make sense? I am not trying to improve my network security. I am looking to improve the stability and robustness of my connection.

Comment: The problem isn't (likely) devices attempting to connect, but simple frequency congestion. I would suggest moving to the 5Ghz frequency band, there is many more distinctly non-overlapping channels (24 vs 3) and is less supported by many devices resulting in far better performance in most cases

Answer (score 0):

Visible/invisible has nothing to do with it. Even if you run your Wifi without encryption no device will try to connect unless the owner ask it to. Your problem is other AP's in the room, specially those on the same channel and closer than 5 channels a part for 2.4 Ghz. 2.4 Ghz is so crowded there is no real solution on this band. Also 5.15 - 5.35 Ghz are also beginging to get crowded, but 5.4 - 5.9 Ghz got enough channels to serve even thousands of people with 11 non overlapping channels. So, if you can upgrade to U-NII 2C or U-NII 3 band you've got a solution.